# DateTime.TryParseExact cannot resolve yyyyMMddHmmss format

Tags: c#

Why DateParse cannot resolve yyyyMMddHmmss for below case?

```
var data = "2017011762000";
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(field, "yyyyMMddHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                DateTimeStyles.None, out var result))
{
   return result;
}
```

I dont want to parse hours like HH beacuse my input is not adding the 0 on the begging. And its 24h clock.

Comment: So what happens when you get an hour value 10 or higher? This is an ambiguous format, probably why the parser is having a hard time decoding it.

Comment: It's working for higher then 10. What is interesting, when I try yyyy MM dd H mm ss with value 2017 01 17 6 20 00 it's working too

Comment: Yes, because it's ambiguous, but adding the spaces removes the ambiguity.

Comment: According to the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=netframework-4.8. _If you **do not use date or time separators** in a custom format pattern, use the invariant culture for the `provider` parameter and **the widest form of each custom format specifier**. For example, if you want to specify hours in the pattern, specify the wider form, "HH", instead of the narrower form, "H"._

Comment: @Jasen That's an answer right there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TryParse` is expecting `HH` instead of `H`. You can add a `0` manually

```
var data = "2017011762000";
data = data.Insert(8, "0");
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(data, "yyyyMMddHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                DateTimeStyles.None, out var result))
{
   return result;
}
```

How do you handle the case when the hour is 11 for example anyway? In case you will have 2 digits then, I guess you can do something like this to add the 0 only when its needed:

```
if(data.Length==13)
    data = data.Insert(8, "0");
```

But my advise would be to fix the issue at the source (where you receive the data from) if you can.

EDIT: Jasen's answer covers why it will not work with the current format of the string.

Comment: It's not true. Its not expecting HH. When I try yyyy MM dd H mm ss with value 2017 01 17 6 20 00 it's working.

Comment: It works when you use separators. It doesn't work when you don't.

Comment: @down_town_the see Jasen answer to explain why it will not work this way

Answer (score 4):

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=netframework-4.8).

> If you **do not use date or time separators** in a custom format pattern, use the invariant culture for the provider parameter and **the widest form of each custom format specifier**. For example, if you want to specify hours in the pattern, specify the wider form, "HH", instead of the narrower form, "H".

As pointed out by others -- including spaces have added separators to the format string.

Comment: Also, to give a reason for this. Imagine you want to use the format string `Hm` where the minutes and hours could be either 1 or 2 characters, then the value of `215` could be interpreted as `21:05` or `02:15`.